# How to increase speed of BLE scanning Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want make some application, it will scanning nearby BLE and sending to server via MQTT. But the scanning proccess to slow. I want to increase the speed of scanning.

mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mqtt_active;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button turnon, changeLayout;
    MqttAndroidClient client;
    private boolean state=false;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    public static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    public static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;
    public static String mqtt_server,mqtt_port,mqtt_id;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        turnon = findViewById(R.id.turnon);
        changeLayout = findViewById(R.id.mqttSet);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        textView.setText("id "+mqtt_id+" port "+mqtt_port+" server "+mqtt_server);
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://"+mqtt_server+":"+mqtt_port,mqtt_id);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stateCheck();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
        final Handler handlerStop = new Handler();
        handlerStop.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                handlerStop.postDelayed(this, 2000);
            }
        }, 2000);

        turnon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!state){
                    turnon.setText("Turn Off");
//                    if (bluetoothAdapter!=null & bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
//                        if(checkCoarsePermission()){
//                            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
//                        }
//                    }
                    if(mqtt_server!=null||mqtt_id!=null||mqtt_port!=null){
                    try {
                        IMqttToken token = client.connect();
                        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection failed!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
                    state = true;
                }else{
                    turnon.setText("Turn On");
                    state = false;
//                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });

        changeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MqttActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void stateCheck(){
    if (state){
        if (bluetoothAdapter!=null & bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if(checkCoarsePermission()){
                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    }else {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    }

    private boolean checkCoarsePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action= intent.getAction();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int  rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
                String RSSI = String.valueOf(rssi);
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"rssi "+RSSI+" "+device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(mqtt_server!=null||mqtt_id!=null||mqtt_port!=null){
                try {
                    String payload = "rssi:"+RSSI+"mac:"+device.getAddress();
                    client.publish("test",payload.getBytes(),0,false);
                } catch ( MqttException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}

            }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
            }else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION:
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"ALLOWED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Forbidden",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } break;
        }
    }
}
```

mqttActivity.java

```
package com.example.mqtt_active;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MqttActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText server,port,id;
    private Button save;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mqtt);

        server = findViewById(R.id.serverMQTT);
        id =  findViewById(R.id.mqttTopic);
        port = findViewById(R.id.mqttPort);
        save = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity.mqtt_id = id.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.mqtt_port = port.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.mqtt_server = server.getText().toString();

                startActivity(new Intent(MqttActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/turnon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Turn On"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.452" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mqttSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set MQTT"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/turnon"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.073" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.524"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mqttSet"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_mqtt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/serverMQTT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Server"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="MQTT SERVER"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="MQTT TOPIC"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serverMQTT" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mqttTopic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Topic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="MQTT PORT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mqttTopic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mqttPort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Port"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/saveButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.298" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to increase speed of scanning nearby BLE? i expect from this forum, i can increase speed of scanning nearby BLE.

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Your BLE device takes too long to be discovered? Please use a generic BLE scanner like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) and test if it scans faster. Your BLE device is responsible for sending advertisements at a regular interval. If the device sends them every 10 seconds the worst-case scenario would be that you scan it after 10 seconds.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I mean, too long to be continous discovered. How to use nRF connect in android studio? And i want to know, easier using fluuter or android studio for develop BLE scanner app?

Comment: You use nRF Connect like any other app on your phone, not in Android Studio. Regarding your other question: I personally never worked with flutter, you should choose the technology based on your requirements and skills

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I want build my app using BLE scanner and sending to mqtt server. But BLE scanner is too slow to discover another BLE. i dont need another app, i need how to make it faster. The delay in finding other BLEs resulted in the inaccuracy of the indoor positioning system that I designed

Comment: I understand. nRF Connect is a finished app used by many. You should simply use it as a reference. If it also takes long to scan your device using nRF Connect your own app is not at fault and you should look for the problem at the end of your BLE device

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AndroidE There is an error in your implementation: you are using the wrong API to scan for BLE devices, the `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();` API returns the bluetooth devices not the BLE devices. In order to scan for BLE devices use this guide [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-ble-devices)